# Strange behaviour of PHP defined()

Tags: php, environment-variables, apache2, defined

I have set an env var `SetEnv YII_ENV prod` in apache vhost file, because I have the following line in my project:

```
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');
```

The problem is that defined() behaves really weird. I have tried the following code:

```
echo getenv('YII_ENV');
echo '<br>';
var_dump(defined('YII_ENV'));
```

The result:

```
prod
bool(false)
```

I can echo the value of the var, but the defined() returns false. I know I can rewrite the condition, but I am really curious why this is happening.

Comment: Do you understand that `defined` check for definition of __constant__? And `getenv` gets __environment variable__.

Comment: Omg, you are right. This was driving my crazy for hours. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explanation - [`defined`](https://php.net/defined) function

> Checks whether a given named constant exists

So, `defined('YII_ENV')` checks whether **constant** `YII_ENV` is **defined**.

But **environment variable** with same name `YII_ENV` is not a **constant**, it's another entity.

That's why you get your output, which is totally correct.